# Is ROS Indigo supported by ardrone_autonomy

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ros-indigo, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I im trying to work with an AR DRONE 2.0, and I have installed ROS Indigo and ardrone_autonomy package. I wish to know if it will work, or i will have to install a previous ROS, like Hydro or Groovy, to continue working.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206285/is-ros-indigo-supported-by-ardrone_autonomy/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: Yes

There's more information on their [github](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy) page and you can get updates from the SFU lab webpages directly.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-04-03**:
Thank you!